# What is the difference between [] = '' and () = ''?

Tags: python

This issue is really confusing for me. What is actually happening behind the curtains here? Why doesn't the latter work?

```
>>> [] = ''
>>> () = ''
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to ()
```

My theory was that there has to be an object or iterable object on the right and its value/s are assigned to the number of variables from the left side container. This thought was based on:

```
>>> [a] = '1'
>>> [a,b] = '12'
>>> a
'1'
>>> b
'2'
>>> [a,b] = '123'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>> [a] = ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Which also works the same on tuples:

```
>>> (a,) = '1'
>>> (a,b) = '12'
>>> a
'1'
>>> b
'2'
>>> (a,b) = '123'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>> (a,) = ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

But there is something that I miss because this fails:

```
>>> [] = ''
>>> () = ''
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to ()
```

What is going on that breaks the latter assignment?

Comment: My 2 cents: you cannot assign to an empty tuple because there's only *one*, namely `()`.